# How to open a new shell in cmd,then run script in a new shell?

Tags: batch-file, powershell

My computer's OS is win7

I want to use a .bat file to open a new shell, then run script in a new shell

this shell is OSGeo4W Shell

it is located in "C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4W.bat"

so I used

```
cd "C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\"
OSGeo4W.bat
cd "C:\Users\tony\Downloads\11\computingArea" 
ogr2ogr -f CSV my_csv Grid.dbf
ogr2ogr -f CSV csv Grid.dbf
addcenter.exe
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" my_dir ./csv/Grid.csv
copy Grid.shp my_dir
copy Grid.shx my_dir
rd my_csv /s /q
rd csv /s /q
ogr2ogr -clipsrc t.shp test.shp ./my_dir/Grid.shp
rd my_dir /s /q
ogr2ogr -f CSV wellcsv welllocation.dbf
ogr2ogr -f CSV csv test.dbf
computingArea.exe
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" my_dir ./csv/test.csv
rd csv /s /q
rd wellcsv /s /q
move test.shp my_dir
move test.shx my_dir
del test.dbf /q
```

But, this script only open OSGeo4W Shell

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

i had similar problem, and i managed to resolved like this: I had a script file called script.bat with various python and ogr functions. In separate bat file i typed:

```
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.14\OSGeo4w.bat" start cmd.exe /k  script  
pause
```

This bat file calls inital script.bat in OSGeo4W Shell.

*note1: Both bat files must be in same directory.
**note2: In your case script.bat will have content:

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV my_csv Grid.dbf
ogr2ogr -f CSV csv Grid.dbf
addcenter.exe
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" my_dir ./csv/Grid.csv
copy Grid.shp my_dir
copy Grid.shx my_dir
rd my_csv /s /q
rd csv /s /q
ogr2ogr -clipsrc t.shp test.shp ./my_dir/Grid.shp
rd my_dir /s /q
ogr2ogr -f CSV wellcsv welllocation.dbf
ogr2ogr -f CSV csv test.dbf
computingArea.exe
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" my_dir ./csv/test.csv
rd csv /s /q
rd wellcsv /s /q
move test.shp my_dir
move test.shx my_dir
del test.dbf /q
```

and separate bat file will be:

```
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\OSGeo4w.bat" start cmd.exe /k  script
```

and both bat files must be in directory with data (C:\Users\tony\Downloads\11\computingArea). I hope this will work, it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
start cmd /K echo Hello world!
```

It definately works on windows XP, the /K runs the specified command but retains the new cmd prompt!  Hope it is useful!

You could try this if you don't want the cmd prompt to remain:

```
start cmd /C echo Hello world!
```

Comment: Thank you But I have many codes under OSGeo4W.bat
I want to put codes in OSGeo4W (it is a shell)

Comment: OSGeo4W is a linux-based shell.
I tried to use "start OSGeo4W.bat /k echo hello world".it showed up '/k' is not an internal or external command.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I haven't used OSGeo4W I just assumed it was using windows.  Regardless I'll list some options which work on Linux depending on the shell followed by an example using Cygwin.  Maybe it will help..

-> You can use gnome-terminal
Gnome-terminal is a terminal emulation application and the -x specifies you want execute the subsequent command:

```
gnome-terminal -x ./script.sh
```

-> Background Process in the current terminal
You can background the first processes by adding an ampersand (&) to the command line or pressing Ctrl+Z when it is running.  You then enter "bg" to let the process continue.

-> You can use xterm and background the process:

```
xterm -e ./myProcess3 &
```

-> An example using cygwin

```
cygstart /bin/bash -li
```

Hope I got all that right, I actually can't test it right now (new windows build PC).

Answer (score -2):

This is a good question. I'm also trying to do this. You can try putting the rest of the script in another .bat file or in a .sh file and pass this file as an argument to OSGeo4W.bat. The script would be something like this:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\"  
OSGeo4W.bat script_inside_the_shell.bat
```

or

```
cd "C:\Program Files\QGIS Dufour\"  
OSGeo4W.bat sh script_inside_the_shell.sh
```