# How to setting environment variables for QGIS?

Tags: shell, gis

I want to set environment variables for QGIS in Win7.

Because I want to use ogr2ogr & gdal in cmd.

I don't want to use OSGEO4W shell.

Because I tried to write a batch file to use.

Unfortunately,I failed.

[How to open a new shell in cmd,then run script in a new shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716069/how-to-open-a-new-shell-in-cmd-then-run-script-in-a-new-shell)

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to have these 2 environment variables:

```
set OSGEO4W_ROOT=<path to your QGIS folder>
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PATH%
```