# How do I write a batch file that opens a msys shell and then run commands in the shell?

Tags: shell, batch-file, ffmpeg, msys

I'm trying to automate the process of building ffmpeg on Windows 10. I'm following the guide here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC

Everything works fine when I do it manually, however I want to write a batch file that I can run to go through the entire process automatically.

Building requires me to set up the Visual Studio environment and the MSYS environment. This is where I'm having trouble, since running the MSYS environment opens up a new shell. I want to pass the configure/make/make install commands to the MSYS shell after it is opened.

I've tried the solution here: [How to open a new shell in cmd,then run script in a new shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22716069/how-to-open-a-new-shell-in-cmd-then-run-script-in-a-new-shell)

The problem they had looks similar to mine, but the solutions posted there didn't work for me.

Here is the bat file currently:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcvars64.bat"
call "C:\workspace\windows\mingw-get\msys\1.0\msys.bat" start cmd.exe /k bscript
pause
```

and bscript:

```sh
./configure --enable-shared --toolchain=msvc --arch=amd64
make
make install
```

I've tried all sorts of variations like:

```
call "C:\workspace\windows\mingw-get\msys\1.0\msys.bat" /k bscript
call "C:\workspace\windows\mingw-get\msys\1.0\msys.bat" bscript
start "C:\workspace\windows\mingw-get\msys\1.0\msys.bat" /k bscript
start "C:\workspace\windows\mingw-get\msys\1.0\msys.bat" bscript
```

And I've also tried leaving the bscript code in the original batch file.

The configure/make commands will either run in the original cmd window, a new cmd window or wont run at all.

Is there a way to pass commands to the MSYS shell like that?

Answer (score 1):

This might be considered somewhat of a late answer but in the spirit of helping out those who come along here in the future:

The MSYS2 documentation contains a page specific to launching MSYS2: https://www.msys2.org/wiki/Launchers/
From there, we learn that one can launch an MSYS2 environment from a Windows shell like this:

```
C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\env MSYSTEM=MSYS /usr/bin/bash -li
```

If you place this in a `*.bat` file and execute the script, a new terminal window will spawn with bash running under the MSYS2 environment.

The documentation further illustrates how to run something within that bash shell:

```
C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\env MSYSTEM=MSYS /usr/bin/bash -lc python
```

The above would again spawn a new terminal window, load the MSYS2 environment, launch bash and then run the python executable in that bash instance.

From here, either directly run the program you want to (instead of `python`) or create a bash script and pass the parameter to that script to the bash invocation to execute a regular bash script within the MSYS2 environment from a Windows Batch file :)

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if you get the result.
you can run command in windows console:
"C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd -mingw32 -shell test-script"

---

*Command & paramerter comment:

C:\msys64\msys2_shell.cmd : msys launching bat

-mingw32 : arch, I use the 32bit

test-script : the startup script in /usr/bin

And you need to set the $PATH in startup script to launch your command*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).